# Why do "Registration-bots" exist? What do they gain from registering on my site?

Tags: ecommerce, registration, captcha

I've been developing some anti-bot procedures for a website, but only because I see others doing it. Why is this necessary? What do the bots gain from registering hundreds of accounts? I'm building an e-commerce website and the only thing registered users can do is make purchases. Should I actually waste time creating an anti-bot procedure (captcha, email verification, etc.)?

I have Googled this but I can't find an answer. I know that bots that register on forums are able to spam it with adverts, but what about sites that don't allow a user to 'communicate' with anyone?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, fake accounts are bad for your site. They could significantly hurt your site's reputation.

1. When they register, your site probably sends an email to a bad address or an address that belongs to someone that didn't register on your site. That makes you look like a possible spammer.
2. They could use the accounts to degrade performance on your site (this is one of the most concerning because if they triggered this using automated techniques it'd be very difficult to stop without inconveniencing your real users)
3. They could use the fake accounts to skew your performance metrics in areas like abandoned carts by customers, etc.
4. They could abuse features like refer a friend and sending wishlists to other email addresses that will then mark your emails as spam (If you have those available).
5. When you go to send a newsletter at a later date, your list may be filled with bad addresses.

You also have to consider the things they might do that can't be anticipated.

Comment: #1 I did not quite understand, right now its so a registered user is asked to verify their e-mail address. Can you elaborate?

#2 and #3 However seems like an excellent reason to implement this. Never thought about that!. Great point at the end too. Excellent answer, thank you

Comment: Actually, I think i misunderstood #1, now I understand it as if a bot enters genuine e-mail addresses of other users, is this correct

Comment: On #1, two things, if your site frequently sends emails to non-existent gmail accounts (for instance) Gmail may choose to just throw all emails you send to the spam folder. That would hurt your legitimate gmail users. Say the bot put a real gmail account, but not to someone that actually registered, that person may then mark the registration email from you as spam, and your reputation with gmail goes down.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this answer doesn't actually address "why", which I believe is the main part of the question

Answer (score 10):

When an online account's password is compromised, the hackers will sometimes sign the victim up for accounts on a ton of other online services. They hope that their actual nefarious activities are lost in the flood of confirmation emails. [Mailchimp says this](https://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/signup-forms/about-fake-signups) on the subject:

> Sometimes, when an abuser attempts to takeover an account, they'll sign their target up for a several email lists at once. They hope that all the new emails in the target’s inbox will overwhelm them and distract them from malicious activity.

Dima Bekerman wrote [a firsthand account](https://www.imperva.com/blog/amazon-account-hack-registration-bots/) of what that looks like. I've included the most relevant portions below, but the whole post is interesting and definitely worth a read.

> I only noticed that something was odd when I opened Gmail one night and found hundreds of registration confirmations to numerous services I’d never heard of. What’s more, I was receiving a similar email every few seconds.
>
> When most of the noise had been cleared, I found an Amazon email hidden among the junk. It informed me that my purchase—one I hadn’t made—would be delivered within 24 hours.
>
> [image: Diagram of the attack]

If your website sends a "Welcome" email to new accounts (and it probably should), it needs to prevent bots from signing up. Otherwise you might contribute to an inbox flood. This can even get you flagged by a blacklist operator like Spamhaus, as [outlined by Brian Krebs](https://krebsonsecurity.com/2016/08/massive-email-bombs-target-gov-addresses/), preventing your *real* customers from receiving emails from you.

Instead, follow this guidance from Dima's preventative tips:

> - **Filter registration bots** – This tip is for site owners. Filtering registration bots can help prevent the attack described here, while also blocking any number of phony subscriptions to your service. This can be achieved by implementing Captcha as part of your registration process.