# How should I handle the problem of people entering others' e-mail addresses without annoying them with "verification" e-mails?

Tags: email, security, forms, email-address, email-accounts

I have forms on my in-development website which require the person to enter an e-mail address.

I don't want to have to send them a "verification" e-mail with a URL containing a code, or instructions such as "please reply to this e-mail to verify that you sent it". This is extremely likely to cause problems such as them not receiving it, or not seeing it, or forgetting about it, or don't want to click on URLs for whatever reason. I know that it's "best practice" according to numerous online guides for e-mail, but in reality, it's a major chore for everyone involved.

And having a text such as:

> If you wish, you can click this link to verify that you sent this: blablabla

feels pointless since most will not bother unless they *have* to.

If somebody enters a nasty message into the form and states their enemy's e-mail address, my system will therefore assume that the person owning that e-mail address submitted the form, and perhaps I will add him to my "blackhole list" without considering that it may not be them. And then, when they later actually want to use the service, they can't, because I added them to my list of e-mail addresses to silently ignore, because some entirely different person "framed" them.

Maybe this doesn't happen often in practice, but I've had it happen to me personally, so I know that it *does* happen, at least sometimes. I've received angry e-mails from people replying to me after somebody wrote something mean and used my e-mail address.

Comment: It is called a double opt-in and you leave the step out at your peril.  The easiest way to handle it is to send the verification message.  If the person doesn't respond within a period (7 days?) then delete their details.  Don't blacklist or anything, just delete it.  Then if the real owner ever decides to join, they can.  Simple.

Comment: By in-development, do you mean that only a very limited number of users should be accessing it?  If so, have you considered limiting access to the entire website to your authorized users?  Limit by IP, limit with OAuth, or some other mechanism?

Comment: Not really worth an answer, but if you're not going to _verify_ the e-mail address, consider what value collecting it is giving you. Either don't collect it at all, or make _the whole field_ optional (but verification mandatory if an address is provided.)

Comment: Either you *do* need the user's email for something, in which case you need to verify it, or you *don't* need it, in which case your form should not require it. I don't see any middle ground.

Comment: innocent typos in email addresses are very common, how else will you catch them?

Comment: @arp you can partially handle this concern by having user enter email twice and doing an MX lookup against the domain name.

Comment: Note that it annoys people much more if you start to send status notifications or if you publish their wrongly given email address to others which start to mail them. Therefore whenever you store an email make sure it’s verified before using/displaying(!) it

Comment: If you don't require verification then please at least minimally provide a link in the emails sent for the recipient to disavow the account. I have quite a common name and get a ton of mail to my gmail account from people signing up to services and entering my email address incorrectly. It's annoying how few companies address this possibility

Comment: @Eliott Having to compose an email to a "new address" with a specific code would be much more annoying than simply clicking a link in a received email - don't you think? You also don't get an immediate confirmation response. And it's much harder to implement.

Comment: @Eliott, for about 20 years, that was more or less the standard procedure for signing up to an email list.  It was quite a relief when the the World Wide Web came around and you could sign up by just entering your email in a form and replying to a confirmation email.

Comment: _" This is extremely likely to cause problems such as them not receiving it, or not seeing it, or forgetting about it, or don't want to click on URLs for whatever reason."_ What's the point in having their email address at all, if you don't trust that they're going to receive/read your emails?

Comment: Which part of opening an e-mail and clicking a link do you consider *"a major chore"*?

Comment: I'll take clicking a link in an email you send me over, say, completing a pointless¹ captcha Every Day Of The Week (and twice on Sundays). It's not, remotely, a "major chore." Please, please don't let people claim that my email address is theirs without the courtesy of dropping me a note to confirm it. *(¹ Bots are better at captchas than humans are now.)*

Comment: @Eliott "I've received angry e-mails ..." - that's really a different problem and a fault of the website/application, as they have evidently used the email _before_ it has been validated.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Be careful what you wish for. "Click to confirm registration" forms sans captcha [have their own attack vector](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/115694/89735).

Answer (score 33):

At its root, this is a problem about verifying ownership of an email address, and as far as I know there are only two ways to practically verify ownership of an email address:

1. Send a verification email, as you mentioned.
2. Complete an authentication flow with the email provider, OAuth-style.

Option 2 works great if your user has an email provider that supports 3rd-party auth, [such as Gmail/Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in). But the only solution guaranteed compatible with most email providers is 1.

In essence, the answer to your question:

> How should I handle the problem of people entering others' e-mail addresses without annoying them with “verification” e-mails?

Is that **it is impossible** in such a way that is fully compatible across all email providers. There is no practical way to verify that someone owns a specific email address besides sending a verification email.

Comment: ... which is, of course, why everybody sends verification emails.

Comment: Note that OAuth can also be used to indirectly verify e-mail addresses from third-party e-mail providers, if the OAuth provider has already previously verified the address e.g. using a verification e-mail. For example, for various reasons, I have three separate Google accounts, but only one of those is linked to a Gmail address. (Another one is my work account, linked to my work address on my employee's domain, while my main account is linked to an address on a domain I personally own, handled by my web hosting provider.)

Comment: I take annoying popups with a remind-me-later option and put the host's email into "remind me later". If they use verification, it doesn't matter. I've still communicated with the host's operator that his ways are annoying.

Answer (score 8):

There is not much you can do to avoid verification mails (in case you actually need to store and verify mails at all, of course): if you display it to users or sent mails to that address, you better make sure the owner has consented.

Besides verifying the email, it also somewhat is used to verify idendity (when more intrusive methods like Government eID, postal challenge, video proof or SMS are not acceptable).

Like mentioned in other answers (and For a particular nerdy audience) you can use OIC/OAUTH or similar social login providers - login with Facebook, GitHub, Google, Live.com, or Apple ID... This has the advantage that it usually also gives you a verified email address.

However, if you need to stick to the ubiquitous email, when you verify them, at least make sure to minimize the annoyance and compliance risks:

- rate limit the mails by receiver and web client ip
- optionally lower the chances for automated submissions with  captchas (maybe coupled to „this ip range tried more than one access per hour“)
- make sure to make the verification mails short and unobtrusive, especially refrain from any advertising or passing along user controlled text (there are some google form invitations which sent you the survey title as spam)
- make sure the verification emails correctly identify your business (reason: besides the general courtesy to identify your business it is also a good idea to not send messages which allow „annoyed“ receivers to sue you on the grounds of formalities like missing business identification and tax number) and have a contact information for a human responder (so they can ask you if harassed via your service)
- make it clear that it is safe to ignored the challenge, but also provide a opt-out link so people can block their Email from beeing challenged (for 6 month or so)
- deny link in the email is actually safer than accepting a „deny me“ form on your web site since only the (annoyed) recipient can use it
- this is also EU GDPR relevant, so make sure to log all transactions around opt-in for proofing due diligence (and make sure to expire those records and not keep the ip addresses indefinite)
- you might want to maintain a deny list for high profile addresses and domains like whitehouse.gov (but this is a losing battle)

BTW some of those points are especially relevant for markets like Germany and EU where lots of legal battles happening around spam, unsolicited mails, data protection and business formalities. You did not specify which area you target, but in a global village it is not a bad idea to target the strictest regulatory framework.

Comment: Most of this answer is inalplicable to the request.

Comment: @davidgo I disagree, but I reworded the intro anyway

Comment: 4 of your bullet points refer to handling the opt-in mail the user explicitly does not want to send...

Comment: I agree with eckes.  "I don't want opt-in emails" should be answered with "you need them, here is why they are a good idea."

Comment: @IMSoP fixed it, was writing a process description about data protection officers before writing the answer, so the O stuck in my fingers